# AWS SNS Text messaging (SMS) failing to send messages

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sms, amazon-sns

I have newly configured SNS to send SMS (Text Messages) for alerts received on a topic. I see the alerts being triggered and I see the SMS Delivery Statistics that all messages failed:

[image]

I have also configured an "Account spend limit" (thinking that this might be the issue). Still all SMS messages are failing.

The Country is listed in the list of countries:

```
Delivery statistics by country (1)
Country        Sent    Failed    Delivery rate
Switzerland    6       6         0%
```

I also configured the "Amazon S3 bucket name for usage reports" but nothing is being saved in my bucket. (I used the AWS help page: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_stats_usage.html and the [Example Policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_stats_usage.html#example_bucket_policy) - replacing my bucket name).

Still:

- no SMS messages are delivered
- no daily reports are saved
- no Technical Support on AWS available for Basic Plan accounts

How can I solve this or continue troubleshooting it?

UPDATE: The email SNS subscription works (I receive the email) and each time I get on Email the Failed SMS number increases (since both subscriptions are active). :(

Comment: Is your region in the list of supported ones? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-supported-regions-countries.html

Comment: Please make sure your configurations are correct and the phone number in E.164 format.  It can be a lot of reasons for SMS failures. If possible enable the cloud watch log.

Answer (score 1):

Cloudwatch Logs is the only option to find out the failure reason.
by default, no user role is attached to SNS so no logs are recorded !

To start recording logs

1.go to AWS SNS Mobile Text Messaging

2.click edit on Text Messaging Preferences

3.in Delivery Status Logging section create a new service role

Now after a sending failure , goto Cloudwatch Logs to view json error response which looks like this

```
{
    "notification": {
        "messageId": "xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxx",
        "timestamp": "2021-04-08 15:37:49.919"
    },
    "delivery": {
        "destination": "+xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "smsType": "Promotional",
        "providerResponse": "Your account requires additional review prior to being able to send SMS messages. Please create a support ticket with an explanation of your use case. https://console.aws.amazon.com/support/cases#/create?issueType=service-limit-increase&limitType=service-code-sns-text-messaging",
        "dwellTimeMs": 100
    },
    "status": "FAILURE"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SMS failures can be due to many things. What's the [provider response](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_stats_cloudwatch.html#example-log-failed-sms-delivery) on the CloudWatch logs for the failed messages? That would be the best place to start debugging.

I would also verify the endpoint's validity against AWS' Pinpoint Phone Validation [endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/developerguide/validate-phone-numbers.html) to see if it returns a valid response back.

```
{
    "NumberValidateResponse": {
        "Carrier": "ExampleCorp Mobile",
        "City": "Seattle",
        "CleansedPhoneNumberE164": "+12065550142",
        "CleansedPhoneNumberNational": "2065550142",
        "Country": "United States",
        "CountryCodeIso2": "US",
        "CountryCodeNumeric": "1",
        "OriginalPhoneNumber": "+12065550142",
        "PhoneType": "MOBILE",
        "PhoneTypeCode": 0,
        "Timezone": "America/Los_Angeles",
        "ZipCode": "98101"
    }
}
```

SNS cannot send messages to `PhoneType` VOIP, Landline or unknown. You can edit your question with the CloudWatch logs if you are still stuck.

If the bucket policy is allowing SNS to add objects to S3, I would wait a few days for it to reflect. Although success messages are logged quickly, failure messages are often retried until their TTL expires and hence it shows up late on S3 - this is similar to CloudWatch logs as well.